# how can i set property data to model field in django

Tags: python, django

```
 class Project(models.Model):
   index = models.IntegerField()
   
   @property
   def index(self):
     function = self.function.name
     frac = self.fraction.name
     operation = self.operation.name
     if function == 'Production' and operation == '2C':
        return frac*9
```

What im trying to do is set the returned value from index property to index field.Dont mind the function,frac and operation variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you 3 options.

1- You can use the `save` method to set the value at creation:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
   index = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if self._state.adding:
         function = self.function.name
         frac = self.fraction.name
         operation = self.operation.name
         if function == 'Production' and operation == '2C':
           self.index = frac*9
    
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

2- You can simply update the instance without a property:

```py
instance = Project.objects.all()[0]
function = instance.function.name
frac = instance.fraction.name
operation = instance.operation.name
if function == 'Production' and operation == '2C':
   instance.index = frac*9
   instance.save()
```

3- If you really want to use a property, first you need to change its name to avoid conflicts:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
   index = models.IntegerField()
   
   @property
   def index_value(self):
     function = self.function.name
     frac = self.fraction.name
     operation = self.operation.name
     if function == 'Production' and operation == '2C':
        return frac*9
     else:
        # Returns something else
```

Then you can assign it to the field:

```py
instance = Project.objects.all()[0]
instance.index = instance.index_value
instance.save()
```

Comment: @emre_000 You need to import the model, use `from app_name.models import Project`, replace app_name with the name of the app that contains it. Also apply migrations

Comment: thank you i tried with the property but it doesnt seem to work but by using save method it worked

Comment: how can i add updating state on if self._state.adding: ? something like this self_state.updating

Comment: @emre_000 use `if not self._state.adding:`